# Problemas con combobox anidado

Tags: php, java, html, jquery, appserv

tengo un problema con un combobox anidado, al momento de elegir del primer list deberia cargar automaticamente el segundo list con el código correspondiente, pero no lo hace, lo que hace es cargarlo pero debo elegirlo manualmente, aquí les dejo la imagen de como se ve: 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```js
//Condición para hallar el conductor por nombre en la asignación de carga según bl.

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#noap").change(function() {

    $("#noap option:selected").each(function() {
      elegido3 = $(this).val();
      $.post("caso2.php", {
        elegido3: elegido3
      }, function(data) {
        $("#noap2").html(data);
      });
    });
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Esto me pasa solo en una PC(Servidor), ya que en mi P.C. y en otras si funciona bien.

Comment: Aporta código a tu pregunta. Así no podremos deducir de que manera ayudarte a tu conflicto.

Comment: @Hoose el codigo funciona bien en todas las maquinas donde lo he instalado, menos en el servidor, que es una maquina con w10 pro, nada del otro mundo :/

Comment: Me refiero a que añadas código a tu pregunta, para poder ayudarte :)

Comment: '<script language="javascript">
//Condici�n para hallar el conductor por nombre en la asignaci�n de carga seg�n bl.
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#noap").change(function () {
           $("#noap option:selected").each(function () {
            elegido3=$(this).val();
            $.post("caso2.php", { elegido3: elegido3 }, function(data){
            $("#noap2").html(data);
   
            });            
        });
   })
});


</script>'